# And condition on multi-valued attribute filter value

Tags: filter, sphinx, multivalue

Here is the structure of my database with products and categories

-- Product Table

```
CREATE TABLE `product_table` (
`product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`product_title` text,
`product_description` text
);
```

-- Product2Category Table

```
CREATE TABLE `product2category_table` (
`product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`category_id` int(11) NOT NULL
);
```

I am creating the multi-valued attribute on category

```
sql_attr_multi = uint prod_cat from query; \
select p.product_id, c.category_id from product as p, product2category as c
            where c.product_id = p.product_id;
```

The relation between product and categories is many to many. As an example a product called lenovo can belong to categories:

```
category_id category_title
    12           sturdy
    20           laptop
```

Question: How should I query using php-sphinx api, find all the products with electronics in their description belonging to both the categories ids 12 and 20. Normally $cl->setfilter('prod_cat',array(12,20) will return even the products belonging to either of the categories. I know if I group concatenate all the categories for a product and do the full text search, it is quite simple. But is there a way to handle with the MVA feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$cl->setfilter('prod_cat',array(12));
$cl->setfilter('prod_cat',array(20));
```

Multiple calls are 'AND'ed :)

---

As an aside, can simplify your MVA query...

```
sql_attr_multi = uint prod_cat from query; \
    select product_id, category_id from product2category
```

Comment: vohhh...Now I read almost whole documentation and could not find that...Great...Thanks....Rather disappointed with the way documentation is done for sphinx....How should I find this kind of stuff..Keep posting on stackoverflow...

Comment: To be fair, the documentation does say "On this call, additional new filter is added to the existing list of filters. "

Comment: Yup my bad...Now I am trying to group the results obtained from the query by the categories. MVA beautifully does this, but only with integer values ie. their ids. Can this be done for the category name as well? Or will I have to write a different query to retrieve the category names corresponding to their ids.

Comment: Yes, just write a seperate query. Its a trivial query.